# SQL query - list of items in one table not in another

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I need some help with a SQL query. I have a table of courses and a table that contains user id and course id, denoting courses that user has taken (might not have taken any; no entry in that table for that user id).

I need a query to return the list of courses **not** taken.

```
Course Category table
    CategoryID
    Caegory

Courses table
    CourseID
    CategoryID
    CourseName
    ...

UserCourse table
    UserID
    CourseID
```

Comment: All courses not taken by any user? All courses not taken by a particular user? All courses not taken per user (i.e. all user/course pairs not in the UserCourse table yet)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will just list the course

```
select *
from Courses C
Left join CourseCategory cc on
cc.CategoryID = c.CategoryID
where CourseID not in (Select CourseID from UserCourse where UserID = 14)
```

Comment: user id will be in UserCourse table only if user has taken the course. The first query returns no result even though I have one user taking all courses from on category. Second one seems to show list of courses not taken by anyone; what i need is for a given user id and course category, what courses within that category have not been taken by this user.

Comment: I added a where clause to the derived table. Just change the value to what you want or use a parameter

Answer (score 1):

you can use `not exists`

```
Select * 
From Courses c 
Where Not Exists (Select 1 From UserCourse uc Where uc.CourseID = c.CourseID)
```

Comment: how do I filter this for a given user id?

Answer (score 0):

> > what i need is for a given user id and course category, what courses within that category have not been taken by this user

(This should have been in the request by the way.)

So:

1. Select from `courses`.
2. Limit to the desired category.
3. Limit to courses not in the set of courses taken by the user.

The query:

```
select *
from courses
where categoryid = 123
and courseid not in (select courseid from usercourse where userid = 456);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way of writing same query, which will perform faster.

```
select C.CourseID,C.CategoryID
from Courses C
Left join CourseCategory cc on
cc.CategoryID = c.CategoryID
left join UserCourse  uc 
on C.CourseID=uc.CourseID
where uc.CourseID is null
```